# Match a string with changing parameters and an optional suffix also with one

Tags: regex

I am struggling the following issue:

I need to be able to match the following two strings:

```
create 3 users prefixed with "user" by username "admin"
create 3 users prefixed with "user"
```

The closest regular expression I came out with is:

```
create (\d+) users prefixed with "(.*)" (?:by username "(.*)")?
```

So, the first string is being matched, but the second one is not, obviously because of the space before the optional part.

I tried more variations like:

```
create (\d+) users prefixed with "(.*)" ?(?:by username "(.*)")?
create (\d+) users prefixed with "(.*)"\s?(?:by username "(.*)")?
create (\d+) users prefixed with "(.*)" *(?:by username "(.*)")?
create (\d+) users prefixed with "(.*)"\s*(?:by username "(.*)")?
```

But none of them helped because the second group for the first string is detected as: **user" by username "admin"**

Comment: Use `create (\d+) users prefixed with "([^"]*)"(?: by username "([^"]*)")?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Tried this one as well, but then again "user" by username "admin" " is detected as the second argument... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the space inside the optional, and make your stars non-greedy:

```
create (\d+) users prefixed with "(.*?)"(?: by username "(.*?)")?
```

The problem you were facing was that the first (greedy) capture would swallow everything from the first quote to the last quote, making the optional not needed. Switching to non-greedy quantifier, you can make the user names reasonable. The alternative is to explicitly exclude the separator:

```
create (\d+) users prefixed with "([^"]*)"(?: by username "([^"]*)")?
```